# Will the hot Atlantic shape global/local weather and if so, how?

Tags: meteorology, oceanography, weather-forecasting, mesoscale-meteorology, predictability

So the Atlantic Ocean exhibits record-breaking temperatures currently with about **1 degree Celsius above-average mean surface temperatures**. [This](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/north-atlantic-heat-record-sea-surface-temperature) article, for example, mentions that a more severe hurricane season might be one possible result.

I was wondering if there are any educated guesses or even probable predictions as to what the short-to-mid-range influence on weather in North America, Europe, Northern Africa, and the Caribbean will be. Maybe a stronger jet stream due to a stronger meridional temperature gradient or a wetter autumn in Europe with increased evaporation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More important is the behaviour of the AMOC (Atlantic meridional overturning circulation) with developing climate change. This collapse leads to very different effects, e.g. that the water masses are distributed more poorly and heat up. This reduced heat transport in the water has effects on global scales. For example, that the trade winds increase.

If you want to know more, I would recommend this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41558-022-01380-y